# Using MongoDB with Restangular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, rest, restangular

I'm new with MEAN and now I have a problem which I can't solve. On server side for providing a REST API with express I'm using library [node-restful](https://github.com/baugarten/node-restful). So there I have this schema Sport.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// create a schema
var SportSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

// export the model schema
module.exports = SportSchema;
```

and controller SportController.js

```
var restful = require('node-restful');

module.exports = function (app, route) {

    // setup the controller for REST
    var rest = restful.model(
        'sport',
        app.models.sport
    ).methods(['get', 'put', 'post', 'delete']);

    // register the endpoint with the application
    rest.register(app, route);

    // return middleware
    return function (req, res, next) {
        next();
    };
};
```

On the client side I'm using library [restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) as AngularJS service to handle Rest API Restful Resources. Here is controller main.js which use it:

```
angular.module('clientApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Sport) {

        $scope.sports = Sport.getList().$object;
        console.log($scope);

    });
```

In Firebug I see that object $scope so that works fine and also I can use object $scope.sports in my template. But what I want here is using mongoosejs' commands, for example

```
angular.module('clientApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Sport) {

        // find each sport with a name matching 'Run'
        Sport.findOne({ 'name': 'Run' }, function (err, sport) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            console.log(sport.name); // <-- does not work
        });

        $scope.sports = Sport.getList().$object;
        //console.log($scope);

});
```

Is it possible to do it? I'm really new in MEAN so I apologize if I'm doing something totally wrong.

Comment: no you cannot do that. Sport is restangular object so you can only call its methods it doesnt know if you are using mongo node  or anything... All it knows api signiture...

Answer (score 0):

So you have a functional MongoDB and you now just want to list a sport that contains 'Run'?

Put a ng-model in the html element that is supposed to do something with the output. Say you want to list all the sports containing run in a list:

```
<any-html ng-model="findonly.name" value="Run">
```

Or perhaps as a modifiable box:

```
<input ng-model="searchSport.name" placeholder="Search for sports by name">
```

Which you can then use as an Angular filter

```
<table> <th>...</th> 
<tr ng-repeat="Sport in sports" | filter:searchSport.name:strict"> <td> {{Sport.name}}
</td></tr></table>
```

or in case of the first example use

```
filter:findonly.name:strict"
```